# gtk-warning ** locale not supported by c library

Tags: games, locale

I was trying to install UT99 as explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Games/Native/UnrealTournament) and [here](https://gist.github.com/soifou/e863b978d1f01e33691b#file-install-ut-goty-debian-jessie-64bits-md). After downloading libraries I needed, I started to install the program, but later on I got the warning as in subject.
I don't understand which is the problem, in other words, the phrase "Locale not supported C library" doesn't explain what is the error.

I try to watch inside my system as:

```
$ sudo locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
it_IT.utf8
POSIX
```

Then if type

```
$ sudo locale -a
LANG=it_IT.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="it_IT.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="it_IT.utf8"
LC_TIME="it_IT.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="it_IT.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="it_IT.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="it_IT.utf8"
LC_PAPER="it_IT.utf8"
LC_NAME="it_IT.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="it_IT.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="it_IT.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="it_IT.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="it_IT.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

At this point I stopped my installation.
Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got a warning, not an error. But does the program work?
I notice that you show the same command twice:  $ **sudo locale -a** but
with different output. Umm, I suppose that is a wrong copy/paste action.
More important, at least I think it could be important, is the empty variable

> LANGUAGE=

In your system I would have expected it to be: **LANGUAGE=it_IT**. If that does not help, you could try to change your locales to **en_US** and if the warnings.
On the UT website I see they have a community/forum. I suggest you post your question there also. Good luck.

Comment: No, `LANGUAGE` may well be unset, so it doesn't explain it. (OTOH I have no own suggestion.)